# Confused about how to switch from redirection to keyboard input

Tags: assembly, stdin, dos, io-redirection

I am attempting 'fix' a DOS application (assembly source available) from years back in regards to using redirection properly.  The DOS application is a command line application that uses keyboard input to enter commands, etc.  The application is supposed to be able to read in a script file containing text commands using redirection.  This does work, the redirected files commands are read properly but the upon completion, the application hangs and no longer allows keyboard input.

The assembly routine uses the DOS 21h Func 6 (console input/output).  I've been experimenting with the DOS 21h functions attempting to resolve this issue but cannot seem to find an answer.  I would appreciate some tips on how to switch back to keyboard input after the redirected file input has completed.  There should be a way to cancel the redirection mode and revert to normal stdin.
Thanks for any tips you might offer.
Jim

Comment: Simplest would be to close the stdin/stdout handles (process handle numbers 0 and 1), then open the "CON" device twice. Could allow to configure this for another device name. Alternative is to read and write terminal I/O using the ROM-BIOS interfaces (int 16h and int 10h) upon reaching EOF in DOS I/O.

Comment: Instead of redirecting stdin and then having to reopen the terminal, it might have been a better design to have your input functions take a file handle, so script input can be handled by passing a different handle instead of the one for stdin.  But then you can't use the usual functions that do implicit stdin and stdout, so I don't know how (in)convenient that would be with DOS assembly.  C stdio has equivalents for every function, like `fgetc` vs. `getchar`.  But with your code designed the way it is now, yeah that can probably work if you can reopen the console and redirect from it.

Comment: @ecm   Thanks,  closing and then reopening CON did the trick.  I am not sure why opening CON twice was required, however.